# AES Algorithm S Box uniqueness

Tags: aes

This is regarding AES algorithm.

Suppose i have implemented a AES algorithm and encrypt data using my algorithm. Now suppose somebody else also has implemented the same AES algorithm (128 bit). Now if i encrypt a data using my algorithm is it possible for decrypting the data and getting back the original data using the second algorithm that the other person has developed. What is the underlying difference in the algorithms.

Is it something related to S-BOX

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AES is a specified algorithm. If you have two different implementations they both should be able to encrypt and decrypt without any difference. If there is a difference then at least one of them wouldn't be AES.

For such things you

1. Either assume all implementations of an encryption algorithm you want to be interoperable with are correct, including yours.
2. Or don't reinvent the wheel unless you actually want to learn something about wheels.

Comment: Actually i have a hardware with me which has capability to perform AES encyption and decryption and this is a 3rd party hardware and the same party have provided a DLL to encrypt and decrypt the data. Now my question is can i have my own AES implemenation to talk with the hardware device in 128 bit AES CFB mode

Comment: Well, sure, as long as both parties implement the algorithm correctly.

Comment: then isnt there something called the S-Box. I thought this S-box will be different for different implementations. is it not the case. can you probably give me a link which would give me more information on the same

Comment: The S-box should be the same for every implementation. In fact, you can find it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box